# ida:Domain un-used setting?

Tags: c#, authentication, openid

When creating an authenticated C# MVC Project it creates an app setting called ida:Domain

However this is never used anywhere in the code generated and as we're using Open ID I cannot see any benefit to having it in the config.

Please can someone tell me if it is used under the covers by any IIS or Microsoft library and what for?

Answer (score 0):

I found this question unanswered. Although it is late, but still no harm doing that.

These configurations are used by ASP.NET MVC Identity service to manage `IDentity and Access (IDA)` for Azure Active Directory users.

Hope that helps.